# Which for loop should I use for JavaScript arrays and objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I always use `for (i=0; i<array.length; i++)` when looping through arrays.

I always use `for (var i in object)` when looping through object properties.

I can't use `for (i=0; ... )` for object properties, but I *can* use `for (var in ...)` for arrays, because arrays are objects too.

The question I ask is: should I dump `for (i=0; ... )` completely and use `for (var in ...)` for **both** arrays and objects? Is there a performance hit? Why would I use one over the other?

Comment: This is pretty much a dup, or at least strongly related to, [an S.O. question viewed over 160K times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea).

Comment: @RayToal I agree. The "related questions" system here is good, but not good enough it seems. :)

Comment: _However_ one thing I am concerned about that the other question didn't bring up: **performance**.

Comment: Agreed.  It is very hard to know when the questions are nearly the same.  However, the one I linked to should have some very good reasons for the practice of avoiding for-in for arrays and so should be helpful to you.  Good point about the performance aspect not being covered though!

Comment: @RayToal I definitely agree. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Actually performance is addressed in one of the comments linking to [this article](http://vocamus.net/dave/?p=1205) :)

Comment: @zsawyer Your eyes are better than mine. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

> should I dump `for`

You shouldn't. `for..in` when used to loop arrays doesn't care about the index and it will list properties attached to the object as well. Stick to `for` for arrays and `for..in` for objects.

An excerpt from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> `for..in` should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order
>   is important... There is no guarantee that `for..in` will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties...

As for the performance, I wouldn't worry about it, because `for..in` to loop indexed arrays is obviously not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I made a jsperf for you :

http://jsperf.com/for-vs-for-in43

Basicly, it is testing perfomance and you can see a huge performance drop when using `for(var i in array)`.

That being said, you souldn't drop the `for`for `for in`.

Comment: +1 for the perf which addressed the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

> can't use for (i=0; ... ) for object properties, but I can use for
>   (var in ...) for arrays, because arrays are objects too.

You should use `for` as the other answers already state.

But you can use `Object.keys(yourObject)` to list the object's keys as an array, then use the for loop on that array.

```
var keys = Object.keys(myObject);
for(var i = 0, key; key = keys[i]; i++) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Although I'm hesitant to use it because of browser support, this sounds like a great way of doing it. +1

Comment: @Jared true, although the support is pretty good excluding older IE and Opera: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/

Comment: I'm counting down the days until I can stop supporting IE8.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a fast responsive code then:

for arrays the `while( l--)` and the `for(i=0,..)` loops are the fastest one...

in object arrays you can only use for in... but if your code is good it does no happen very often that you loop through an object.

fastest loops:

```
var myarray=[1,2,3,4,5,6],
length=myarray.length;//here i cache the length of the array.
```

caching the array length is another important thing to keep the code fast.

```
while(length--){
//do somethingwith your array
 //myarray[length];
}
```

while was the fastest loop in older browsers .. in new browsers it looks like the for loop is a little faster.

```
for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
//do somethingwith your array
//myarray[i];
}
```

now if u wanna define variables, do that before you loop.

there is also a nice comparsion that shows you the performance even if sometimes the code is not written very well.

http://jsperf.com/fors-vs-while/61

so if you plan to loop through an array always use while-- or for(var i=0..) caching the length.

another loop that i really like if u have arrays in multidimensional objects like json is this one

```
for(var a=0,b;b=my.very.long.object[a];++a){
//do somethingwith your array 
//b
}
```

another mistake that most ppl do is they use push in a loop...
executing push in a loop means u executea new function every time.
as we already have "i" that is a index we can set that and use it to store the data directly without executing a new function

so

```
//wrong
for(var i=0,newArray=[];i<length;i++){
newArray.push(myarray[i]);//this is a waste of time and resources
}
//right
for(var i=0,newArray=[];i<length;i++){
newArray[i]=myarray[i];//we already have an index.
}
```

ps.:feel free to correct my bad english but don't touch the code!.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that the order of enumeration is not guaranteed, so for..in on an array may return values out of sequence. It will also list all properties, including those that are not numeric (i.e. would not be returned by iterating over an index) and enumerable properties on the object's `[[Prototype]]` chain, so you must always use it with a *hasOwnProperty* test if you only want own properties (the most common case).

If you're using an ES5 host, then you have methods like [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.4) and [Object.keys](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) to get own properties. But again, order is not guaranteed.

Lastly, *for*, *do* and *while* loops are highly optimised, there is very little difference in performance and what is faster in one browser may be slow in another. Just use what suits and optimise only if performance is an issue.